# How I can correct my c code?

Tags: c, variables, types

I can't get the output that I need. The output should be :

```
error =1
correction=0.1
```

How repair my code to get the output above.

```
    int weight[3] = { 1, 0, 0 };
    int x[3] = { 1, 0, 0 };

    output = 1;

    float error, d;
    int sum = 0, i, n;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + x[i] * weight[i];
    }



    error = output - n;
    d = error * RATE;

    printf("error= %i", error);
    printf("correction= %i", d);
}
```

Comment: Pay someone $50 to do it.

Comment: printf("error= %f", error);

Comment: (A good question should be able to be summarized in the title; this usually is merely a result of *explaining* the behavior and/or *describing* the problem, hopefully in relation to a *minimal test-case*.)

Comment: You print value of d as integer , formated with %i, but d is float variable. "printf("correction= %f",d); " may give you desired output.

Comment: sum became 1. n became 1. error became 0. d became 0.

Comment: *The journey of a thousand miles begins beneath one's feet.* - [**Lao-tzu**](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/24004.html)

Comment: The journey of a thousand miles begins on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

this works perfectly in my environment!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int error = 1;
    float correction = 0.1;

    printf("error =%d\n", error);
    printf("correction=%0.1f\n", correction);
}
```

Comment: or better yet, #include <stdio.h> int main() { printf("error =1\ncorrection =0.1\n"); }  Oh yea, and there's a bug in your code.  There is no space between = and the number.  +1 for simplicity.

Comment: @thang , I like your approach better ;) it would be the accepted answer if you post it :D, thnx for showing me the bug, updated ;)

Answer (score 0):

For your calculation, given answer by your program is very correct. So check the given values.

For your values,answer is

```
error = output - n;//0 = 1 - 1
d = error * RATE;// 0 = 0 * 0.1
```